# How does a Monero node know to reject Borromean range proofs

Tags: ringct

Now that Bulletproofs have been deployed, how does a Monero node know to reject any Borromean range proofs?

Is there something like a checkpoint, so that after block N, no more Borromean range proofs are allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous places that check transactions, but perhaps the most pertinent is [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/6335509727661349e50c54c4e0eafd692f0d6907/src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp#L2667), where Borromean range proofs are no longer allowed, based on fork version.